# Stop recursive setTimeout function

Tags: javascript, recursion

Im running a recursive setTimeout function and I can run it many times, it has a clearTimeout, with this property I can handle how to stop the function running.
But I can't figure out how to stop it in another function.

```
var a = 0;
var b = 0;
function Listener(x, y) {
    var lValue = y == true ? a : b;
    if (lValue < 100) {
        console.log(lValue);
        if(y == true){
            a+=x; 
        }else{
            b+=x;
        } 
        setTimeout(Listener.bind(this, x, y), 1000);
    } else {
        clearTimeout(Listener);
        if(y == true){
            a=0; 
        }else{
            b=0;
        } 
    }
}
```

When i tried to run it twice, it works:

[image]

My doubt is: How can I stop a particular running instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could elevate the timer to a higher scope that is accessible by other functions.

```js
var a = 0;
var b = 0;
var timer = null;

function Listener(x, y) {
  var lValue = y == true ? a : b;
  if (lValue < 100) {
    console.log(lValue);
    if (y == true) {
      a += x;
    } else {
      b += x;
    }
    timer = setTimeout(Listener.bind(this, x, y), 1000);
  } else {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    if (y == true) {
      a = 0;
    } else {
      b = 0;
    }
  }
}

function clearTimer() {
  if (timer !== null) clearTimeout(timer);
}

Listener(3, 3);
// clear the timer after 3 secnods
setTimeout(clearTimer, 3000);
```

Answer (score 3):

A couple notes:

- Given the constant timeout of `1000`, you should be using [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) instead. It will greatly simplify your function, and allow you to cancel the interval whenever you want.
- Using global variables is code smell, create an object instead to hold a reference to the value being incremented. Doing so will also allow your function parameters to be more intuitive.

Here's a solution incorporating these two suggestions:

```js
function range (step, start = 0, stop = 100) {
  const state = {
    value: start,
    interval: setInterval(callback, 1000)
  };
  
  function callback () {
    if (state.value < stop) {
      console.log(state.value);
      state.value += step;
    } else {
      console.log('timer done');
      clearInterval(state.interval);
    }
  }

  callback();

  return state;
}

const timer1 = range(10);
const timer2 = range(20);

setTimeout(() => {
  console.log('stopping timer 1');
  clearInterval(timer1.interval);
}, 2500);

setTimeout(() => {
  console.log('timer 2 value:', timer2.value);
}, 3500);
```

Answer (score 0):

create a variable and store the reference of setTimout on that variable, after that you just clearTimout with that variable reference

e.x

GLOBAL VARIABLE:

```
var k = setTimeout(() => { alert(1)}, 10000)

clearTimeout(k)





 var a = 0;
    var b = 0;
    var recursiveFunctionTimeout = null;

    function Listener(x, y) {
        var lValue = y == true ? a : b;

        if (lValue < 100) {
            console.log(lValue);
            if(y == true){
                a+=x; 
            }else{
                b+=x;
            } 
            recursiveFunctionTimeout = setTimeout(Listener.bind(this, x, y), 10);
        } else {
            clearTimeout(recursiveFunctionTimeout);

            if(y == true){
                a=0; 
            }else{
                b=0;
            } 
        }
    }
```

LOCAL VARIABLE:

```
var a = 0;
var b = 0;

function Listener(x, y) {
    var lValue = y == true ? a : b;
    var recursiveFunctionTimeout = null;

    if (lValue < 100) {
        console.log(lValue);
        if(y == true){
            a+=x; 
        }else{
            b+=x;
        } 
        recursiveFunctionTimeout = setTimeout(Listener.bind(this, x, y), 10);
    } else {
        clearTimeout(recursiveFunctionTimeout);

        if(y == true){
            a=0; 
        }else{
            b=0;
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I pass the parameters with your example??

Comment: You can do that as a global variable, or as a local variable inside